# Why “le” instead of “li” to translate them?

Tags: grammar

*Qualcosa mi dice che lui le abbia trovate*

Translation: “Something told me he found **them**”.

Isn't the third person plural direct pronoun *li*?

Comment: Hi, jxhyc. I really dislike constantly playing "bad cop" here, but may I ask, have you consulted a textbook (any textbook) before asking this question? Do you **believe** that there's only one form of plural pronouns in Italian or do you **know** [the forms of pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_grammar#Pronouns)? Please re-read our [on-topic help page](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and try to ask question which could not be aswered by looking in a texbook or in a dictionary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, again. I am sincerely sorry if have caused any inconvenience, and I always greatly appreciate the help i receive. To be fair,  I did did some search before.http://duolingo.wikia.com/wiki/Italian_Skill:Clitic_Pronouns. They didn't listed separately for male and femal clitics plural.

Comment: Listen, there's no inconvenience, we are really glad that you are learning Italian, really appreciate your efforts and try to help as much as we can. But it becomes very obvious that you can't just rely on that Duolingo system - their explanations are incomplete and insufficient for proper learning. You keep facing the same problems (with pronouns, past participle, etc.), because they don't give you the basics you need. I'd suggest you studying with a real textbook and keeping Duolingo only for "tests".

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is exactly  what I am going to do.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence *le* is used to refer to a feminine object. For example: *"Pensi abbia trovato le prove? Qualcosa mi dice che lui le abbia trovate"*.

*Li* is used for masculine objects. For example: *"Dove hai messo i libri? Li ho messi lì"*.